# PHP - how can I show \n \0 \t \x0B \r

Tags: php, hidden-characters

How can I show these characters on a webpage?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?  How do you intent to show them?  You're talking about actually having these characters in your text and translating or converting them into something that shows visually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// An example to replace all newlines with their character equivalent
$value = preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', '\n', $value);
echo htmlentities($value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do the following...

```
<?php
echo "&#92;n"."\n";
echo "&#92;0"."\n";
echo "&#92;t"."\n";
echo "&#92;x0B"."\n";
echo "&#92;r"."\n";
?>
```

Expected Result:

```
\n
\0
\t
\x0B
\r
```

and that should just print to screen, since `&#92;` is the reference for a `\` on web pages.

EDIT:

Looks like StackOverflow auto-changes `&#92;` to a \ when not marked as code!